# DCMTK: Does N-DELETE delete the file from PACS?

Tags: dicom, dcmtk

I want to delete the DICOM file stored on the PACS (SCP). My role will be SCU. Can I do this with the N-DELETE command using DCMTK?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56522201/5779732

Answer (score 4):

N-DELETE is not for deleting DICOM objects in a PACS. It is e.g. used for the Print Management Service, i.e. for deleting a print job or film box.

If you want to "delete" a DICOM object in a PACS, have a look at the [IHE IOCM](http://wiki.ihe.net/index.php/Imaging_Object_Change_Management) integration profile.

Answer (score 2):

As Riesmeier mentioned above, there is no standard DICOM service to delete a DICOM file stored on PACS. N-DELETE command is used by Print Management and RT Machine Verification but not for deleting DICOM files.

Some PACS may allow configuring an AE to overwrite SOP instances stored on the PACS (e.g. overwrite the previous instance) and others may use private service for the task. Private Service may use N-DELETE command or N-ACTION command for the task.

Please, check the DICOM conformance statement of the PACS you are working with or ask the PACS Admin for a solution.